# "unexpected end of stream" when downloading a large file

Tags: android, http, android-networking

I try to download a large file using the snippet from the following url: [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog). However, it only works with small file. When I try to download a large file such as [this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/StJohnsAshfield_StainedGlass_GoodShepherd-frame_crop.jpg), I get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:48)
```

What's the problem? Is it because the server closes the connection for long connection?

Comment: You did not tell wich sourcecode line caused the error. Cannot reproduce your error. The indicated file downloads ok with the supplied code.

Comment: @greenapps java.io.InputStream.read